# How to write this if..else conditional statements with Ternary Operators:

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-8, conditional-operator

I want to write this if..else statements with ternary operators:

```
if((($request->city)=="98")&&($cartPrice >= 300000)&&($request->province)=="8")){
    "ort_free_delivery" => 'City sending free delivery'
}elseif((($request->city)!="98")&&($cartPrice >=300000)&&($request->province)!="8")){
    "ort_free_delivery" => 'Country sending free delivery'
}else{
    "ort_free_delivery" => '',
}
```

And here is my try:

```
( ( ($request->city)=="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)=="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "City sending free delivery" ) ); 

( ( ($request->city)!="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)!="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "Country sending free delivery" : "ort_free_delivery" == "" ) );
```

But this is wrong because there are two lines of ternary operators, and I need this condition in one line (because I'm inserting some data with DB class in Laravel):

```
    DB::table('order_detail')->insert([
        "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
        "ort_amount" => $value->price,
        "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_type" => "product",
        "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
        "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
        ( ( ($request->city)=="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)=="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "City sending free delivery" ) )
        ( ( ($request->city)!="98" ) ? ($cartPrice>=300000) ? ( ( ($request->province)!="8" ) ? "ort_free_delivery" == "Country sending free delivery" : "ort_free_delivery" == "" ) )
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ]);
```

So my question is how can I add this conditional statement with ternary operators in one line ?

**UPDATE #1**:

I tried this to check if the conditions work or not:

```
if ($foundOrder != null) {
                DB::table('order_detail')->whereOrtOrdId($orderId)->delete();
                foreach ($foundOrder as $key => $value) {
                    $existProduct = DB::table('order_detail')->whereOrtOrdId($orderId)->whereOrtReferenceId($value->id)->exists();
                    if (empty($existProduct)) {
                        $price = Product::wherePrdId($value->id)->select('prd_sale_price')->first();
                        if($request->city==98&&$cartPrice >= 300000&&$request->province==8){
                            dd('city');
                        }elseif($request->city!=98&&$cartPrice >=300000&&$request->province!=8){
                            dd('country');
                        }else{
                            $data["ort_free_delivery"] = '';
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                DB::table('order_detail')->whereOrtOrdId($orderId)->delete();
            }
```

And it properly shows `city` and `country` if their conditions return true,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is

```
$data=[
        "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
        "ort_amount" => $value->price,
        "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
        "ort_type" => "product",
        "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
        "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
        "created_at" => now(),
        "updated_at" => now()
    ];  
    
if($request->city==98&&$cartPrice >= 300000&&$request->province==8){
    $data["ort_free_delivery"] = 'City sending free delivery';
}elseif($request->city!=98&&$cartPrice >=300000&&$request->province!=8){
     $data["ort_free_delivery"] = 'Country sending free delivery';
}else{
    $data["ort_free_delivery"] = '';
}
```

Then query

```
  DB::table('order_detail')->insert($data);
```

or

```
DB::table('order_detail')->insert([
    "ort_ord_id" => $orderId,
    "ort_amount" => $value->price,
    "ort_total" => $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
    "ort_discount" => ($value->price * $value->quantity) - $value->discounted * $value->quantity,
    "ort_type" => "product",
    "ort_number" => $value->quantity,
    "ort_reference_id" => $value->id,
    "ort_free_delivery" =>($request->city==98&&$cartPrice >= 300000&&$request->province==8)?'City sending free delivery':
        (($request->city!=98&&$cartPrice >=300000&&$request->province!=8)?'Country sending free delivery':null),
    "created_at" => now(),
    "updated_at" => now()
]);
```

Comment: This is wrong bro. I tested this and data does not get inserted into the DB.

Comment: @tejoslaeslio check properly whether if else works properly. Not sure your condition satisfies or not .also updated answer

Comment: I just tried second option and it shows `syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ']'`. And if I remove `;` from the sentence I get `Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)``

Comment: @tejoslaeslio try first one .once it work then second can modify. Since its long expression ternary is not recommended way

Comment: I just tested the conditions and they work fine (see **UPDATE #1** plz). But I don't know why the first option does not work !

Comment: @tejoslaeslio check condtion satisfy or not and also change ->exists() return one or 0 i mean true or false so it wont be empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234489/discussion-between-john-lobo-and-tejoslaeslio).